# MySQL starts with searching issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm having an issue using the `%` wildcard with a MySQL query.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Having read that article, I am using `%` and not getting quite what I was expecting.

I have a  series of values, such as

```
1_1
1_2
2_1
2_2... etc
```

including

```
11_1
11_2
```

Now, in some cases I want to return specifically those whose value = `11_2`, or `1_2` etc. This works fine

```
WHERE fieldName = '11_2'
```

etc... as expected

However, in some cases I want to find all items which start with a `1` or all items which start with `11`

From the w3Schools link, I was expecting

```
WHERE fieldName LIKE '1_%'
```

To find anything that begins with `1_` specifically, therefore, in my example, returning:

```
1_1
1_2
```

BUT, it also returns

```
11_1
11_2
```

Why is this? And how can I over come it?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Underscore is a wildcard for a single character. You will need to change your SQL to something like:

```
WHERE fieldName LIKE '1%'
```

Or you can escape the underscore

```
WHERE fieldName LIKE '1\_%'
```